# Kill connected ovpn client from openvpn server

Tags: lubuntu, openvpn, kill, client

How can I kill the connected ovpn client form openvpn server via command line.

Comment: Answered here: https://serverfault.com/q/900544/294606

Answer (score 1):

Do not waste time by reading the full answer. Just read cases in bold font.

To answer your question correctly:

- I've installed openvpn server, configured it and generated certificates and keys
- Installed docker, downloaded ubuntu-18.04 docker image and run it with `--privileged` option to be able to run openvpn
- Ran openvpn in docker container `openvpn client.ovpn` being in `/etc/openvpn/client` folder, where `client.ovpn` config file, keys and certificates are located
- **Added `management localhost 7505` line into `/etc/openvpn/server/server.conf` file**
- Restarted my openvpn server: `sudo systemctl restart openvpn-server@server`
- Connected to openvpn server's management port using telnet: `telnet localhost 7505`
- Ran the next commands to temporarily stop current openvpn connection:

  The `status` command shows who is connected:

  ```
  status
  ```

  Output (shrank):

  ```
  CLIENT_LIST,ubuntu,172.17.0.2:37372,10.8.0.6,,22078,142535,Tue Mar 31 17:22:32 2020,1585664552,UNDEF,0,0
  ```

  The next command kills client by its openvpn client name (`ubuntu` in my case that is next to `CLIENT_LIST`)

  ```
  kill ubuntu
  SUCCESS: common name 'ubuntu' found, 1 client(s) killed
  ```

  or (use identifiers next to `UNDEF`)

  ```
  status
  CLIENT_LIST,ubuntu,172.17.0.2:38653,10.8.0.6,,40110,45567,Tue Mar 31 17:36:22 2020,1585665382,UNDEF,1,0

  client-kill 1 0 "temporary"
  SUCCESS: client-kill command succeeded
  ```

  But they kill openvpn session temporarily. Openvpn session auto refreshes after some time.
- **To disconnect openvpn user, use the next commands (2 0 are identifiers that located next to `UNDEF` word):**

  ```
  status
  CLIENT_LIST,ubuntu,172.17.0.2:45455,10.8.0.6,,4632,7272,Tue Mar 31 18:24:03 2020,1585668243,UNDEF,2,0

  client-deny 2 0 "denying"
  SUCCESS: client-deny command succeeded
  ```

My `/etc/openvpn/server/server.conf`:

```
$ cat /etc/openvpn/server/server.conf | grep -v '#' | grep -v ';' | grep -v '^[[:space:]]*$'
management localhost 7505
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert serv.crt
dh dh.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist /var/log/openvpn/ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
verb 3
explicit-exit-notify 1
```

My `client.ovpn` conf:

```
$ cat /etc/openvpn/client/client.ovpn | grep -v '#' | grep -v ';' | grep -v '^[[:space:]]*$'
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote 172.17.0.1 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
key-direction 1
remote-cert-tls server
tls-client
tls-auth ta.key 1
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
verb 0
```